# Python - Add json data from a text file to a single field of csv file

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a text file containing data comma separated and within that I also have json data, so I am trying to make a csv file from it but the json data splitting  into different columns instead of coming under same column. In that case I need some help.
**Sample Data:**

> 1,'22',2068,'zxzx@gmail.com','SCHEDULED',1,0,'2017-11-30 18:16:23',NULL,NULL,'**{\"endpoint_AudioE2ELatency\":0.0,\"endpoint_VideoE2ELatency\":0.0,\"inboundrtp_inboundJitter\":0.004044444300234318,\"inboundrtp_bytesReceived\":28223,\"inboundrtp_packetsLost\":0,\"inboundrtp_remb\":0}'**,NULL,NULL,NULL,**'{\"inboundrtp_inboundJitter\":0.0017291667172685266,\"inboundrtp_bytesReceived\":46411,\"inboundrtp_packetsLost\":0,\"inboundrtp_remb\":0,\"endpoint_AudioE2ELatency\":0.0,\"endpoint_VideoE2ELatency\":0.0,\"outboundrtp_roundTripTime\":0.317474365234375,\"outboundrtp_targetBitrate\":64265.0,\"outboundrtp_bytesSent\":87360,\"outboundrtp_packetsSent\":546,\"outboundrtp_packetsLost\":1,\"outboundrtp_remb\":0}'**,1

So this highlighted data needs to come in the same field of csv file.
**This is my code so far:**

```
rg= re.compile('\{(?:{[^{}]*}|[^{}])*}')
def analyze_log(f):
stats = OrderedDict()
for line in f:
    if (rg.search(line)):
        stats = re.findall('\{(?:{[^{}]*}|[^{}])*}',line)
    else:
        stats = line
    return stats


def write_stats(stats, f):
   out = csv.writer(f)
   out.writerow(stats)

def main(input_filename, output_filename):
    with open(input_filename) as input_file:
        stats = analyze_log(input_file)
    with open(output_filename, 'w') as output_file:
        write_stats(stats, output_file)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(r'input.txt',
         r'Output.csv')
```

Here in analyse_log() I am getting the json part in same field but missing the other data.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you considered converting all of the data to a json stream and working with it that way? Then you could use the python json libraries

Comment: Add an escape character to the csv before running the scripts to every comma in the json

Comment: If your only remaining issue is analyse_log() not having all of the data, it is because you override your `stats` variable each time it is run with what is returned from your regex search (the JSON data).  Instead of using `stats =` in the if/else conditions of your function, you should come up with some key to save the data into the OrderedDict, i.e. `stats['somekey'] =`

Comment: @GracefulRestart I got your point and assigning the keys to stats will work but I am not getting any proper key or somekey for stats.

Comment: is there a reason you are using an OrderedDict for stats instead of a list?  The list will keep everything in the order they were added.  You would use a dict when you have keys you can assign data to, or you could assign the line number as the dict key.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, you have the incorrect csv settings in your writer.

In the write_stats method, change the out assignment to the following and see if you get better output (you want your quotechar to be a single quote as you have double quotes in your json):

```
out = csv.writer(f, quotechar="'")
```

As for why you only get the json data in your output, it is because that is what you are searching for in your regex in the analyze_log method (it only returns the json data).  It would probably be easier to use the csv python module to parse your file instead of using a custom regex.

EDIT:  adding some code

Your method with regexes would be best if the JSON data was not always in the same columns for every row.  Though, if the JSON data is always in the same columns, you can just use the corresponding list indexes.  I was able to extract just the JSON in your data sample without using regexes using the following code:

```
import csv
with open('input.txt') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar="'")
    for row in reader:
        print row[10], row[14]
```

Comment: When parsing the file using csv module json part is splitting in different fields.

Comment: Without using regex how will I get the json data in one field

Comment: i made an edit with some code that worked with your sample data

Comment: Thanks for the help but yes the JSON data is not always in the same column.